# Orientation of magnetic flux in a induction motor?

Tags: induction-motor

1) The rate of change of stator flux creates rotor emf and current which in turn produces rotor flux. What is the relationship between stator flux and rotor flux? In what direction is the rotor flux oriented with respect to stator flux?

I assume that spatially both flux would be orthogonal if rotor pf is close to 1 and 180 degree if rotor pf is close to 0.  Am i right?

2) How are poles of the rotor in induction motor decided?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because This appears to be homework.

Comment: I am just an electrical enthusiast learning things on my own and i am not going through a formal education program for this. So please dont consider it as homework, i am just fulfulling my curiosity. If the question is simple do share links which i can go through.